# Modeling change in relative abundance of two groups through time

Tags: regression, biostatistics

Lets say I have two species, A and B, and I have calculated their relative abundance at many different sites. The relative abundance is expressed as

### $rel.abundance = \frac{abundance.A} {(abundance.A + abundance.B)}$

I collect this data at two time points, `t1` and `t2`. I want to model how the relative abundance metric has changed. specifically:

$metric = \frac{rel.abundance_{t2} - rel.abundance_{t1}} {t_2 - t_1}$

This metric will take the value of 1 when a community composed of only species B transitions to only species A, and -1 if a community of only species A transitions to only species B. This metric will take the value of 0 if the relative abundance of A and B has not changed.

I had been using zero-one inflated beta regression to model the relative abundance of species A at `t1`, however I'm not sure where to start on modeling the change.

Comment: I can't see that this displayed measure will ever become negative. It will vary between 0 and 1. So, how you are measuring change, which is the central issue here?

Comment: @NickCox If a community at `t1` only contains species B, then the metric will be 0. If at `t2` that community only contains species A, then metric will be 1. Therefore, the change in the metric will be 0 - 1 = -1.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the question is now shown up as poorly written "... how the relative abundance metric has changed. It will take the value ...": evidently the antecedent of "it" is meant to be the change in relative abundance, not the relative abundance as written. What you want to say is clear once that is understood, but I'd rewrite the question nevertheless. "It" like "this" is poisonous to clarity unless the antecedent is completely clear.

Comment: More to the point, this is relative change in relative amount. That's quite a severe data reduction. Going from 1 A to 1 B is treated the same as going from 1 million A  to 100 B. Perhaps your research goal makes that the right reduction; perhaps not. Hard to comment further on this information.

Comment: Have you considered modeling the abundances directly, rather than the change in this ratio? That might provide more ability to evaluate potentially interesting issues such as whether high overall abundance might favor A over B. Results could still be expressed in terms of changes of the ratio,if you wish.

Comment: @NickCox thanks, will clarify. Unfortunately, the relative change in relative abundance is the thing of most interest, for a number of biological reasons. Total abundance turns out to be pretty uninformative for this particular research question.

Comment: @EdM I have modeled the changes in total abundance of both species directly, and I do get interesting results that suggest a change in the total relative abundance. How would I go about fusing together two separate models of the abundances of each species, to determine if the end of day relative abundance has shifted?

Comment: You could form a single model that has abundance as the dependent variable and includes species as one of the predictor variables. At first thought it seems that testing an interaction of species and time would give you what you want, although I haven't thought that through carefully. Consider re-writing this question (or posing another) to focus on this "fusing" of what now seems to be two separate models. Including some examples of data in the question is often desirable and may lead to more helpful answers.

Comment: A change measure bounded by $-1$ and $1$ can be modelled using a logit link once you've rescaled to (change $+1$)/$2$. This is equivalent to using Fisher's $z$ transformation on correlations.